# Google Analytics tracking pixel custom dimension?

Tags: google-analytics

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-???????-?&cid=??????????????&t=event&ec=ProductView&ea=eventAction_here&el=eventLabelValue&dimension1=dimensionValue

When using that link as an img src, it triggers an event. I would like to know if I would be able to set the dimension value in this tracking pixel. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: This is probably off topic as  it's not related to coding, but to add the custom dimension you would add cd<customDimensionSlot>=value to the URL. But how would you achieve this? Using GA sendHitTask or buildHitTask?

Comment: It's sort of ghetto, but i'm dynamically creating a url that fills in the parameters in the url in php and sending it off to google which retrieves a 1 x 1 px img.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set a custom dimension via the Measurement Protocol (what you're calling the tracking pixel) using the [`&cd<dimensionIndex>=`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cd_) parameter.

To make sure your Measurement Protocol hits are valid, you can test them using the [Measurement Protocol Hit Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/).

Comment: Thanks you for your help! I'm trying this now!